# onActivityResult not being Overridden and never reached in a Button.ClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, onactivityresult

I'll start saying I just hope this isn't something so stupid I couldn't notice it, but after hours of researches I haven't found my answer. In my `SMSActivity` I have created a `Button cmdApriRubrica` which opens the Contacts default app and then when a Contact is selected returns its data to my activity, theorically (I've looked this up at [Android Developer Basic Trainings](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)). The Contacts app opens fine, but the problem is I never get the result. My code is the following:

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.cmdApriRubrica)).setOnClickListener( new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
            pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
            startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            //super.onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data); CAN'T CALL THIS

            // Check which request it is that we're responding to

            if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // Make sure the request was successful
                    // Get the URI that points to the selected contact

                    Uri contactUri = data.getData();

                    // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result

                    String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

                    // Perform the query on the contact to get the NUMBER column
                    // We don't need a selection or sort order (there's only one result for the given URI)
                    // CAUTION: The query() method should be called from a separate thread to avoid blocking
                    // your app's UI thread. (For simplicity of the sample, this code doesn't do that.)
                    // Consider using CursorLoader to perform the query.

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();


                    // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column

                    int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                    String nome = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String numero = cursor.getString(column);

                    Log.i("Dati contatto: ","Nome = "+nome+", numero = "+numero);


                    // Do something with the phone number...

                    txtDati.setText(new StringBuilder().append(nome).append("\t------------\t").append(numero).toString()); //Android Studio suggested me doing this...
                }
            }
    });
```

I think the main problem is that I'm in the `onClick()` event: I've looked out for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment) answer, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239761/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-activity) answer, [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15394) bug, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment/#24303360) answer, [this](http://blog.shamanland.com/2014/01/nested-fragments-for-result.html) site and some other less voted answers. Many suggested to call `super.onActivityResult` but it doesn't find the method, so I can't call it. Also, Android Studio tells me that the onActivityResult I wrote there doesn't override its superclass's method. Why does this happen? I haven't found any answer about this. Is there a way to avoid writing this inside the `onClick` method, if this is the problem, or am I doing something wrong I couldn't find a solution about? Thank you for your time.

---

EDIT: I have modified the code as I've been suggested; my code is now the following:

```
    TextView txtDati = null; //This is initialized just below the class declaration to have it visible
    public static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQ_CODE = 200;
        ...
        findViewById(R.id.cmdApriRubrica).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
                pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
                startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQ_CODE);
            }
        });

        ...
//At the same level of the onCreate() method, as I've been told!
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request it is that we're responding to

        if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && txtDati != null) {

            // Make sure the request was successful
            // Get the URI that points to the selected contact

            Uri contactUri = data.getData();

            // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result

            String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

            // Perform the query on the contact to get the NUMBER column
            // We don't need a selection or sort order (there's only one result for the given URI)
            // CAUTION: The query() method should be called from a separate thread to avoid blocking
            // your app's UI thread. (For simplicity of the sample, this code doesn't do that.)
            // Consider using CursorLoader to perform the query.

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();


            // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column

            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            String nome = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String numero = cursor.getString(column);

            Log.i("Dati contatto: ","Nome = "+nome+", numero = "+numero);


            // Do something with the phone number...

            txtDati.setText(new StringBuilder().append(nome).append("\t------------\t").append(numero).toString()); //Android Studio suggested me doing this...
        }

        else
            Log.i("Problem ActivityResult","Something wrong in onActivityResult method!");
    }
```

I now get this exception but I can't understand how the Cursor.query works very well:

---

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=200, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/3045 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.fun.is.activity.gguiduzzi.orariobello/com.fun.is.activity.gguiduzzi.orariobello.SMSActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

---

Can someone please tell me where's the problem? I've been looking so hard for it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here in my opinion. You are using the method OnClickListener from Button. You should use View.

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.cmdApriRubrica)).setOnClickListener( new Button.OnClickListener() { WRONG

((Button)findViewById(R.id.cmdApriRubrica)).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { OK
```

The second problem you have is that you are overriding the **onActivityResult** inside de button listener and not the activity that's why you can't use **super.onActivityResult.**

You should put this code (onActivityResult) at the same level of onCreate, onDestroy, etc.

Comment: So I should override it outside, thank you! Can you explain me please what changes from using Button.OnClickListener to View?

Comment: @njzk2 Maybe wrong was not the correct word here, my fault, i should use "possible change" or something like that. He was looking for a solution to his problem and i answered what i think he could change to resolve it. In the API (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) and in most of the projects i've been part of, use Button.OnClickListener that's why i suggested it.